# Enumerating MP3 files returns too many results

Tags: file, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to enumerate the track lengths of music files in a specified directory.

The test directory contains only 14 MP3 files, no sub-directories and no hidden files.

I have the following script (and I realise I could pipe results, *etc*., but I'm trying to debug something).

```
function Get-TrackLengths($dir) {

    $resolvedPath = (resolve-path $dir)
    $trackLengths = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    $files = Get-ChildItem $dir\* -Include *.mp3,*.flac -File -Recurse False

    Write-Host (-join("found ", $file.Length, " files"))

    foreach($file in $files) {

        $path = $file.FullName
        $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
        $folder = Split-Path $path
        $file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
        $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
        $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)

        Write-Host (-join("`"", $file, "`"", " has length ", $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)))
        $trackLengths.Add($shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27))
    }

    return $trackLengths
}

$trackLengths = Get-TrackLengths "[fully-qualified directory path]"

Write-Host (-join($trackLengths.Length, " Track lengths:"))

foreach($trackLength in $trackLengths) {
    Write-Host $trackLength
}
```

Given the test directory's 14 MP3 files, I would expect to see the following result.

> found 14 files
>   "01 - Track 1.mp3" has length 00:05:30
>   "02 - Track 2.mp3" has length 00:00:45
>   "03 - Track 3.mp3" has length 00:05:19
>   "04 - Track 4.mp3" has length 00:04:31
>   "05 - Track 5.mp3" has length 00:04:06
>   "06 - Track 6.mp3" has length 00:04:59
>   "07 - Track 7.mp3" has length 00:04:29
>   "08 - Track 8.mp3" has length 00:01:04
>   "09 - Track 9.mp3" has length 00:04:03
>   "10 - Track 10.mp3" has length 00:04:55
>   "11 - Track 11.mp3" has length 00:04:12
>   "12 - Track 12.mp3" has length 00:05:05
>   "13 - Track 13.mp3" has length 00:08:17
>   "14 - Track 14.mp3" has length 00:02:59
>   14 Track lengths:
>   00:05:30
>   00:00:45
>   00:05:19
>   00:04:31
>   00:04:06
>   00:04:59
>   00:04:29
>   00:01:04
>   00:04:03
>   00:04:55
>   00:04:12
>   00:05:05
>   00:08:17
>   00:02:59

However, what the result actually shows is

> found **19** files
>   "01 - Track 1.mp3" has length 00:05:30
>   "02 - Track 2.mp3" has length 00:00:45
>   "03 - Track 3.mp3" has length 00:05:19
>   "04 - Track 4.mp3" has length 00:04:31
>   "05 - Track 5.mp3" has length 00:04:06
>   "06 - Track 6.mp3" has length 00:04:59
>   "07 - Track 7.mp3" has length 00:04:29
>   "08 - Track 8.mp3" has length 00:01:04
>   "09 - Track 9.mp3" has length 00:04:03
>   "10 - Track 10.mp3" has length 00:04:55
>   "11 - Track 11.mp3" has length 00:04:12
>   "12 - Track 12.mp3" has length 00:05:05
>   "13 - Track 13.mp3" has length 00:08:17
>   "14 - Track 14.mp3" has length 00:02:59
>   28 Track lengths:
>   0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   10
>   11
>   12
>   13
>   00:05:30
>   00:00:45
>   00:05:19
>   00:04:31
>   00:04:06
>   00:04:59
>   00:04:29
>   00:01:04
>   00:04:03
>   00:04:55
>   00:04:12
>   00:05:05
>   00:08:17
>   00:02:59

Two questions:

1. Why does it say that it found 19 files - especially when it lists only 14 files?
2. When listing the track lengths, why does it write out 0-13 first, saying that there are 28 elements in the `$trackLengths` array?

Comment: You're using $file.length instead of $files.length?

Comment: Jeez, stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing that out - been staring at it for too long. But how about those numbers 0-13 in the `$trackLengths` array?

Comment: Just playing around with that now, it's something to do with the way you populate that array but then also return the result from the function, haven't quite nailed it yet.

Comment: It's probably something else the function is returning. One classic PowerShell mistake is assuming the Return statment defines the only thing that the function returns, but actually anything that writes output to the pipeline is also being returned.

Comment: Yeah, do this: $trackLengths.Add($shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)) | Out-Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues with your code, the first was just a simply typo of  `$file.length` instead of `$files.length`.

The second was this line:

```
$trackLengths.Add($shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27))
```

Which needs to be this:

```
$trackLengths.Add($shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)) | Out-Null
```

As it was returning an output (probably the index of array item added) as well as adding the item to the array. When using a PowerShell function beware that the `Return` statement does not define the only thing returned by the function, anything that writes output will also be returned.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mark, I'd have been Googling and staring at this for a long time to come.